# How to style window.alert in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

How to style `window.alert` in Bootstrap?

Code example:

```
something
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
        result => {
            console.log(result);
            window.alert(result.description);
            window.location.reload();
        },
        error => {
            console.log(error);
            window.alert(result.description);
            window.location.reload();
        }
    );
```

Comment: The browser alert dialog cannot be styled. That's one of the reasons to never use it. Use a modal dialog to display your alerts and style that.

Answer (score 3):

You can not style window `alert`, you can use bootstrap `modal` instead of alert.

More info at: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

Answer (score 1):

The style of these alter windows are defined by the browser.
You have to write your own browser :D

An alternative could be maybe Toasts messages.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this applies to your situation, but this was possible for me. You can append the alert to an element and set the innerHTML to html with bootstrap markups. In my case, here is a trimmed down request catching the message:

```
destroyRock(div){
    useAPI.deleteFetch("rocks", this.id)
    .then(jsonToJS).then(message => this.graduate(message, div))
    ...
}
```

the next function BEFORE with a regular window alert:

```
graduate(m, div){
    div.remove()
    window.alert(m.message)
}
```

AFTER with a bootstrap alert:

```
graduate(m, div){
    div.remove()
    const nav = document.getElementById("mainNav")
    let alert = document.createElement("div")
    const gradAlert = `
        <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
            <strong>Congrats!</strong> ${m.message}
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        `
    alert.innerHTML = gradAlert
    nav.append(alert)
}
```

I don't love it appended to the nav so I'm going to play around some more as to where it's going, but hope this helps someone in the future!